# How many solutions to $x^2-4x-\cos x=-8$?

Tags: trigonometry, quadratics

> $$x^2-4x-\cos x=-8$$ 
>   We want the number of solutions.

Now I tried taking $\cos x$ as constant but by formula for root we get a trig equation which can't be solved. Any help? Thanks!

Comment: $\cos{x}$ certainly cannot be treated as a constant and thus the quadratic formula is just not useful here. You have to think more carefully about the functions $x^2 - 4 x + 8$ and $\cos{x}$ and how many times they will cross each other.

Comment: only number of soln

Comment: @Archis Welankar \ The answer by Kay K. is well-thought-out and pithy. Why don't you register your appreciation by ticking the check-mark denoting that you accept the answer? Good luck.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$$x^2-4x+8=\cos x$$
$$L.H.S=(x-2)^2+4\ge4$$
$$R.H.S\le1$$
Therefore, the number of solutions is zero.

Comment: Okay what i was thinking was i rather consider it as const then its range is $-1,1$ then vertex of parabola is $y term=-4$ thus height is -4 from y where cos can never reach so no solution

Comment: I think you can think that way too.

Comment: But still thanks.